# Problema com desalocação de ponteiro em lista encadeada

Tags: c, ponteiro, osx, lista-encadeada, allegro

Estou já há uns dias com um problema na desalocação de ponteiros em um código meu. Eu tento fazer com que se o ponto do meu objeto na tela for maior que um valor, desaloque este objeto da memória, mas por algum motivo isso não está funcionando e esta dando um erro que trava tudo.

Enfim, acredito que eu esteja fazendo algo muito errado, mas não consegui identificar o que é, segue o código:

Esta é a estrutura que eu estou usando para a criação da lista

```c
//estruturas
//asteroide
struct Asteroides {
    int x;
    int y;
    int vel;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *Img;
    int id;
    char palavra;
};
//um tipo de variavel lista que eh um ponteiro
typedef struct elemento* Lista;
//define elemento
struct elemento {
    struct Asteroides dados;
    struct elemento *Prox;
};
//define um tipo de elemento auxiliar
typedef struct elemento Elem;
```

Esta é a alocação dos elementos na lista:

```c
//insere na lista
void ins_list(int num, Lista* li){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        Elem* no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
        if(no == NULL) break;
        no->dados.Img = Asteroide;
        no->dados.x = (rand()%1000);
        no->dados.y = -200;
        no->dados.id = i;
        while(no->dados.vel <= 0 || no->dados.vel >5){
            no->dados.vel = (rand()%10);
        }
        no->Prox = (*li);
        *li = no;
    }
}
```

Esta é a parte que eu tento a remoção sem sucesso, o código da remoção é junto com o da atualização da imagem:

```c
//anima asteroides
void anima(Lista* li, int frame, int agFramex, int agFramey){
    Elem* no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    Elem* ant = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    no = (*li);
    ant = no;
    while(no != NULL){
        al_draw_bitmap_region(no->dados.Img, agFramex*frame, agFramey*frame, frame, frame, no->dados.x, no->dados.y, 0);
        if(no->dados.y > ALT+200){
            ant->Prox = no->Prox;
            free(no);
            no = ant->Prox;
        }
        no->dados.y += no->dados.vel;
        ant = no;
        no = no->Prox;
    }
}
```

O if é o código da remoção:

```c
if(no->dados.y > ALT+200){
   ant->Prox = no->Prox;
   free(no);
   no = ant->Prox;
 }
```

Eu recebo `segmentation fault 11` que de fato é erro de alocação, alguém consegue me ajudar? Obrigado.

**Obs:** O erro ocorre quando o primeiro objeto atinge a condição.

Comment: faz tempo que não faço nada em c e mal lembro a sintaxe do ponteiro então talvez não seja isso, mas acredito que seja porque quando o primeiro objeto é removido e a memória dele é liberada, o ponteiro no seu código principal que aponta para o inicio da sua lista, continue apontando para esse objeto já liberado. imagino que você deveria passar uma referencia da posição de memória desse ponteiro e caso seja o primeiro objeto a ser removido, o ponteiro de inicio da lista fosse atualizado

Comment: Cara eu não sei se está certo, mas faz muito sentido! Eu vou verificar

Comment: cara C é elgal,e  você pode estar se divertindo muito com os ponteiros e etc... Mas se estiver mais a fim de se preocupar com a mecanica do jogo em si, e não em ficar maquinando como faz uma lista, ou outra estrutura de dados trivial que no fundo não tem a ver com o jogo, Sugiro dar uma olhada em Python, com a biblioteca Pygame - ou mesmo com o Allegro - acabei de verificar que o allegro mesmo já vem com bindings para Python.

Answer (score 0):

Um problema aí (não posso garantir que seja o único) é que quanfo há uma remoção de item, você avança duas vezes para o próximo no: uma ao fazer a remoção e outra no final do while.

Se o `no` removido for o último da lista, `ant->Prox` (e portanto `no`) vai apontar para `null`  , e logo depois do `if` você faz `no->dados.y += no->dados.vel;` que deve ser a causa do seu segmentation fault.

Uma solução é executar a atualização e avanço do no somente se o no não for removido:

```
while(no != NULL){
        al_draw_bitmap_region(no->dados.Img, agFramex*frame, agFramey*frame, frame, frame, no->dados.x, no->dados.y, 0);
        if(no->dados.y > ALT+200){
            ant->Prox = no->Prox;
            free(no);
            no = ant->Prox;
            continue;
        }
        no->dados.y += no->dados.vel;
        ant = no;
        no = no->Prox;
    }
```

(A inserção do comando 'continue' acima passa o fluxo do programa imediatemente para o teste do `while` que é a coisa certa a se fazer ai: `no` já está apontando para o que antes era `no->Prox`.

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma solução, mas uma sugestão.

Porque razão perder tanto tempo a utilizar listas encadeadas se pode usar Arrays?

Quando se está a aprender não se pode esquecer dos básicos. A meu ver listas encadeadas para um jogo não faz sentido.

A minha sugestão seria utilizar na estrutura `Asteroide` um `bool` que contém se o asteróide está vivo ou não. Depois com Arrays apenas desenhava e atualizava os vivos.